# In Godzilla (2014), why did MUTO 2 go anywhere at all?

Tags: godzilla-2014, monsterverse

I am confused. I just watched *Godzilla* (2014). It was pretty straight forward except for one thing, why did MUTO 2 leave its place of plentiful resources? Did I miss the movie dialogue that explained why the MUTOs opted for the relatively paltry amount of radiation that they settled for compared to the unlimited supply MUTO 2 abandoned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The two MUTOs established a communication and a biological imperative had them move toward each other. Without a catalyzing amount of radioactivity, the final development of MUTO 2's clutch would not have been possible.

- We are unsure how much information is encoded within the MUTO's communications, few that there were. For all we know, those brief bursts were filled with logistical data. Or it could have been as simple as "Out of food, bring more".
- MUTO 1 having far greater mobility would obviously seek out a food source and bring it to MUTO 2, who was land-bound AND gravid. She would seek out a place to nest and likely wait for MUTO 1 to arrive.
- More importantly, the movie established the creatures absorbed all the radioactivity from their location, leaving an area complete bereft of any radiation. (Early foreshadowing scene underground with opened egg sack and giant skeleton).
- MUTO 2's location (as a waste facility) would not likely be a place anyone would check to see if it had remained radioactive, since the expected shelf life of most of that material was 50,000 years or more. It is safe to assume, she had already consumed all of the radioactivity in the facility before leaving.
- Since it was not specified, MUTO 2 could have also been unable to detect radiation in the highly shielded underground bunkers, once she had consumed everything within her own individual containment unit. To her senses, there may have been no food available due to the lead shielding within the bunker, hence her need to be on the move.

Answer (score 1):

After feeding on the radiation in Utah, the MUTO left in order to travel to meet with MUTO 1 to breed and build a nest. At that point each of the MUTO was traveling towards the other leading to the scene in SF

Comment: But why? MUTO 2 was ideally situated and ready to set up shop once MUTO 1 came to her.

Comment: I've got nothing to definitively back this up, but I imagine it's a biological imperative, coupled with the fact that their only communication was a basic call-and-response. MUTO 1 & 2 only knew that the other was awake and ready to mate.

Comment: In addition the humans knew their location and were trying their hardest to kill them.

Answer (score 1):

It's simple biology, really -- the MUTOs want to mate, and to do so they must meet: MUTO 1 is drawn to MUTO 2, and MUTO 2 is drawn to MUTO 1, so logically they both move toward the other and meet in the middle.

In nature things like this happen all the time, with one or the other seemingly abandoning a source of plentiful food in order to mate; after mating, though, often one (or, in some species, both) parents will seek out food and bring it to the nest; in other cases, the male will donate his genetic material, and the female will then wander off to build a nest for her fertilized eggs somewhere where there *is* food.

In this case,

> the military obviated any such need by delivering food to the pair, practically on a silver platter!

Without that, we really have no basis for determining what would have happened. It's possible, for example, that the eggs would have hatched and the new younglings would have set out in search of food (this is also common in the natural world, especially among insects, which the MUTO do seem to resemble in many respects); the convenient in-nest food Mom provided merely assures a higher survival rate -- we have no basis for assuming that that was in fact a necessity, and

> the complete lack of any reaction from the eggs when the warhead was removed seems to suggest that it was *not*, in fact, a necessity.

Ultimately, though, we're relying entirely on speculation here -- there was no dialogue that you missed that addressed this point, and even if there had been it, too, would have been purely speculative anyway, as humanity has never before observed the behavior of *any* Daikaiju before, save Godzilla himself at Bikini (and even that was apparently very limited and short-lived).